# Count activities on contact object

Tags: formula-field, activities, roll-up-summary, count

Is it possible to create a rollup summary field on Contact to count the activities. For example, count the total number of times 'Log a call', total number of times 'log a meeting', and total number of times 'Log an email'?

Comment: I highly doubt that if it's possible you can't create a master-detail relationship with a standard object on the detail side and without being a relationship you can't create a Roll-Up summary

Answer (score 1):

Rollup summary fields can only be used on Master-Detail relationships where you wish to rollup child information to the parent i.e detail to master.

In this case, you need to use Apex. A declarative tool like Flow is possible but to ensure you are working from the correct Related To `Sobject`, you will need to invoked Apex.

Sample Apex:

```
List<Id> conIds = new List<Id>();
for (Task t : Trigger.New) {
    if ((t.WhoId.getSObjectType() == Contact.sObjectType) && t.Subject == 'Log a Call') {
        conIds.add(t.WhoId);
    }
}

if (conIds.size() > 0) {
    List<Contact> cons = [select id, CallLogs__c from Contact where id in :conIds];
    for (Contact con : cons) {
        if (con.CallLogs__c == null) con.CallLogs__c = 1;
        else con.CallLogs__c += 1;
    }
    update cons;
}
```

A custom Number field has been added to the Contact object to count the specific number of "Log a Call" Tasks. You may wish to aggregate all Task Subjects in a single field, thats a design choice on your side. Another design decision for you is to build a known of set of Task subjects to check against. Note the check on `WhoId.getSObjectType()` as Task is a shared object and you want to safe guard your code for later operations.

You should extend this Apex to accommodate `delete` operations if you wish to decrement the count on the Contact record.